# Regex - Match Collection Must Consume Entire String

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
var goodStr = "abcabcabc";
```

I want to write a Regex pattern for it to return three (3) matches, which each one's value being "abc". However, if the string deviates from the repeated "abc" pattern at all, I do not want to return ANY matches.

**Also, I do not know if there will always be 3 repetitions (there could be any number of repetitions).**

For example, the following string should fail, and it should not have any matches:

```
var badStr = "abcabcabc123";
```

What pattern should I use that would return 3 matches in *goodStr*, but 0 matches in *badStr*?

In other words, the sum of the last match's index and length should equal the total length of the subject string.

I am trying not to use captures/back-references in this scenario also.

**EDIT:**

The pattern **^(?:abc)+$** does not suffice since it only returns 1 match.

The pattern **^abcabcabc$** does not suffice since it assumes there will only be 3 repetitions of "abc", and I don't know how many repetitions there will be in my scenario. Also, it only returns 1 match.

> **Solved**
>
> With Aaron's and anubhava's help we made this pattern that works for my scenario:
>
> \Gabc(?=(?:abc)*$)

Comment: What is the pattern you are using? Does it have anchors for the beginning and end of the string `^` and `$`?

Comment: @dvo I edited my question to explain why that doesn't work

Comment: @anubhava I edited my question to explain why that also doesn't work

Comment: Which environment (language? tool?) are you using regex from?

Comment: @Aaron Both PHP and C#

Comment: @anubhava Haha that's what I'm doing currently, and I'm trying to clean it up by not using 2 different patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following in C# :

```
(?<=^(?:abc)*)abc(?=(?:abc)*$)
```

This matches occurences of `abc` from which you're able to reach both the start and the end of the string using only other repetitions of `abc`. This relies on the capacity to use variable-width lookbehinds which is quite rare but that C#'s regex engine implements.

I've been able to test it on http://regexstorm.net/tester where it does return 3 matches for `abcabcabc` but 0 for `abcabcabc123`.

Comment: this works great. thanks. however you can remove the dependence on the variable-width lookbehind by using the \G anchor (maybe you can add this to your answer): (?:^|(?<!^)\G)abc(?=(?:abc)*$)

Comment: @user3163495 I didn't think about `\G`. Including it to my answer would feel like copying anubhava's answer, if you're using a `\G`-based solution you should accept his answer rather than mine

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't support dynamic length lookbehind so you may use this regex using `\G`:

```
(?:^(?=(?:abc)+$)|(?!^)\G)abc
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0o6Rs/1)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

After some more iterations this regex turns out to be most efficient:

```
\Gabc(?=(?:abc)*$)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/T0o6Rs/2)

Comment: I put the \G anchor into Aaron's answer and it works great

Comment: After some more iterations I think `\Gabc(?=(?:abc)*$)` will be most efficient regex

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\G` in combination with a positive lookahead. `\G` matches at the start of the string or asserts the position at the end of the previous match.

You can capture abc and check if what is on the right is a repetition of the group until the end of the string.

```
\G(abc)(?=\1*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovvvUO/1)